# Can I run one SwingWorker within another?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I need to run two `SwingWorker`s.  One of them can only run after the other is done.  Can I run them like this?

```
class TestWorker {
    private FirstWorker worker1;
    private SecondWorker worker2;

    public TestWorker() {
        worker1 = new FirstWorker() {
            @Override
            protected void done() {
                try {
                    result1 = get();
                } catch (Exception) {
                    // exception handling
                }

                worker2 = new SecondWorker() {
                    @Override
                    protected void done() {
                        try {
                            result2 = get();
                        } catch (Exception) {
                            // exception handling
                        }
                    }
                }

                worker2.execute();
            }
        }

        worker1.execute();
    }
}
```

And how should I cancel them? Like this?

```
private cancel() {
    if (worker2 != null) work2.cancel();
    if (worker1 != null) work1.cancel();
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it that way and it will work. However, unless there are other operations in your outer `done` that you're not showing, you would probably be better off with something that did both operations in `doInBackground` and returned an array of the results.